# Cannot access Cloud Firestore with Flutter Web

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I am not able to acquire data from Firebase when running on the web.
I suppose to be able to read documents data but I always fail and the data always return null.

There is no error message or any debug message...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`cloud_firestore` plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) does **not support** *Flutter web* as of yet (January, 2019).

However, there currently is an [open pull request](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/pull/1670), which will add Flutter web support to the plugin soon. You can track the progress on GitHub.

In the meantime, you could resort to the [`firebase`](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase) plugin and handle your Cloud Firestore mobile and web implementations separately. This is a lot of effort and waiting for the PR or trying to depend on it instead might be a better option.

---

You can always check what platform a Flutter package supports on Pub:

[image: Pub badge]

This would include "**WEB**" if there was web support for the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I guess now it is supported under [Firebase for Web](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase)

And [this](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/) is how to use it.

Check it out. Hope this helps